# Opencv 2 Mat- Error on runtime

Tags: c++, opencv

I am starting with the basics of image processing and I am trying to convert a RGB image into grey scale using averaging.

My code is

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat image = imread("a.jpg");
    namedWindow("Original ");
    namedWindow("Grey");
    imshow("Original", image);  
    Mat grey;
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            grey.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = (image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] + image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] + image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2]);
        }
    }
    imshow("Grey", grey);
    return 0;   

}`
```

I think there is some problem with the Mat Grey , while accessing the element inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your `grey`,

```
Mat grey(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
```

And then, during processing,

```
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
    {
        grey.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = ((image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] + image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] + image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2]))/3;
    }
```

The `/3` will give you the **true** grayscale value.

HTH

Comment: If you are talking about weighted division, then that isn't true grayscale; that is just considering the colors which have the highest response in the human vision system.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the definition of your "true grayscale"?

Comment: Every grayscale transformation is done by `Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B`. And by the way, OpenCV loads the images in BRG mode.

Comment: This definition is indeed correct for Grayscale conversion based on human perception since cones are most sensitive to Green. If, however, a **true** conversion it to be applied, the weights should be distributed equally. This would ensure that a perception system has the best response to all the colors and not just one.

Comment: so you are saying that your grayscale is true because is not human? Strange... Anyway, Can you give a link that sustains your idea?

Comment: It is not "my" grayscale; it is the conceptually correct representation of a multi-channel image as a single channel image. The weighted conversion has been used sRGB representation after cones' sensitivity analysis. Look it up in Gonzalez's Color image processing chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, You have not initialized it, so it is empty, you cannot access the elements.

`Mat grey = Mat::zeros(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);` Should fix it.

Try using an if statement before accessing the elements of a `Mat`:

```
if (grey.empty())
{
  std::cout << "Empty Mat!\n";
  return -1;
}
```

Another thing is that adding the image channels are not the true grayacale, [see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale).